# Why my boolean if else is return to the else statement even though my sql is correct?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `btom` (
  `idabom` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `bomt` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `btom` (`idabom`, `bomt`) VALUES
(1, '2019-02-01'),
(2, '2019-02-02'),
(3, '2019-02-03'),
(4, '2019-02-04'),
(5, '2019-02-05'),
(6, '2019-02-06'),
(7, '2019-02-07'),
(8, '2019-02-08'),
(9, '2019-02-09'),
(10, '2019-02-10'),
(11, '2018-11-11'),
(12, '2019-02-12'),
(13, '2018-12-13'),
(14, '2019-02-14'),
(15, '2019-02-15'),
(16, '2019-02-16'),
(17, '2019-02-17'),
(18, '2019-02-18'),
(19, '2019-02-19'),
(20, '2019-02-20'),
(21, '2019-02-21'),
(22, '2019-02-22'),
(23, '2019-02-23'),
(24, '2019-02-24'),
(25, '2019-02-25'),
(26, '2019-02-26'),
(27, '2019-02-27'),
(28, '2019-02-28'),
(29, '2019-03-01'),
(30, '2019-03-02'),
(31, '2019-03-03'),
(32, '2019-03-04'),
(33, '2019-03-05'),
(34, '2019-03-06'),
(35, '2019-03-07'),
(36, '2019-03-08'),
(37, '2019-03-09'),
(38, '2019-03-10'),
(39, '2019-03-11'),
(40, '2019-03-12');


ALTER TABLE `btom`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idabom`);


ALTER TABLE `btom`
  MODIFY `idabom` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=41;
COMMIT;
```

Some code from my comments (Unformatted):

```
<?php include("dbconn.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $snum = md5($_POST['snum']);
$user = $_POST['user'];
$tnt = $_POST['bmb'];
$sqltnt = "SELECT * FROM btom WHERE bomt = '$tnt' ";
$querytnt = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sqltnt) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbconn).header("Refresh: 1,index.html"));
$rowtnt = mysqli_num_rows($querytnt);
if($rowtnt==1) { echo " :)";
} else { echo " :("; } } mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: Don't post code in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51926837/edit) your question. Also, SQL Sever <> MySQL. This looks like MySQL, due to your use of Backticks (`\``), so I have removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that a valid and existing value is provided inside `$_POST['bmb']`.
Simply use `echo` to see the value:

```
echo $_POST['bmb'];
```